# Why is the first eventlistener not being triggered after the checkbox checked attribute changes from the second eventlistener?

Tags: javascript, html

When the second eventlistener executes, the checkbox.checked attribute is changed. However the script from the first eventlistener doesn't execute after the checkbox.checked changes. Why?

I'm trying to create a responsive expand/collapse toggle button. In the event all Details close or open, the state of the toggle button should change. In other words, the execution of the second eventlistener should trigger the first eventlistener.

I tried using 'change' event instead of 'input' for the first eventlistener, but nothing happened.

Bootstrap classes are used.

```
<div id="discussion">
    <input type="checkbox" id="expand-collapse-toggle-ckbx" class="btn-check" autocomplete="off">
    <label id="expand-collapse-toggle-btn" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-3d mb-3" for="expand-collapse-toggle-ckbx"><i class="bi bi-arrows-collapse"></i><span> Collapse All</span></label>
    <details open>
        <summary>A</summary>
        This is the first detail summary
    </details>
    <details open>
        <summary>B</summary>
        This is the second detail summary
    </details>
    <details open>
        <summary>C</summary>
        This is the third detail summary
    </details>
</div>
```

```
// Responsive Expand/Collapse All Button
const eleInputCkbx = document.querySelector('#expand-collapse-toggle-ckbx');
const eleLabelIcon = document.querySelector('#expand-collapse-toggle-btn i.bi');
const eleLabelText = document.querySelector('#expand-collapse-toggle-btn span');
const eleDetailsNL = document.querySelectorAll('#discussion details');

eleInputCkbx.addEventListener('input', function() {

    // Change toggle button and collapse all Details elements
    if (eleInputCkbx.checked === true) {
        eleLabelIcon.classList.remove('bi-arrows-collapse');
        eleLabelIcon.classList.add('bi-arrows-expand');
        eleLabelText.textContent = ' Expand All';
        eleDetailsNL.forEach(item => {
            if (item.open === true) {
                item.open = false;
            };
        });

    // Change toggle button and expand all Details elements
    } else if (eleInputCkbx.checked === false) {
        eleLabelIcon.classList.remove('bi-arrows-expand');
        eleLabelIcon.classList.add('bi-arrows-collapse');
        eleLabelText.textContent = ' Collapse All';
        eleDetailsNL.forEach(item => {
            if (item.open === false) {
                item.open = true;
            };
        });
    };
});

eleDetailsNL.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('toggle', function() {

        // Append each Details.open boolean value to array
        const arrDetailsStat = [];
        eleDetailsNL.forEach(item => {
            arrDetailsStat.push(item.open);
        });

        // If all Details are open then check checkbox
        if (arrDetailsStat.every(item => item === true)) {
            eleInputCkbx.checked = false;

        // If all Details are closed then uncheck checkbox
        } else if (arrDetailsStat.every(item => item === false)) {
            eleInputCkbx.checked = true;
        };

    });
});
```

Comment: How about using `change` event instead of `input`?

Comment: As I said before, I tried change instead of input, but nothing different happened.

Comment: Have you tried also triggering the event and not just changing the `checked` property? Because I think, that just changing the property doesn't trigger the event. But I am not a 100% sure. So, adding an event trigger after `eleInputCkbx.checked = true;` for example.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your first event listener (`inputCheckBoxHandler`) will not run when your second event listener (`detailEventHandler`) gets triggered is that in JS `addEventListener()` method sets up a function that will be called whenever the specified event is delivered to the TARGET only [(read more)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and not pragmatically via other functions in your code.

In other words the `input` event will only fire if the event is delivered to the `input` element directly by the user.

There are two options to get your desired behavior here. One is to use `dispatchEvent()` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) and fire it whenever you want. See here:

```
// we create an 'input' event here
const inputEvent = new Event('input');
```

You could then fire it from your code whenever you want it to run the callback function associated with `input` event:

```
// when you want to manually dispatch the input event. It will fire the input event and run its callback function
eleInputCkbx.dispatchEvent(inputEvent);
```

In the second way. I extracted the callback functions in your code into their own functions and tried to run the `inputCheckBoxHandler` when all the details are changed. It will be easier to see it in action here:

```js
// Responsive Expand/Collapse All Button
const eleInputCkbx = document.querySelector('#expand-collapse-toggle-ckbx');
const eleLabelIcon = document.querySelector('#expand-collapse-toggle-btn i.bi');
const eleLabelText = document.querySelector('#expand-collapse-toggle-btn span');
const eleDetailsNL = document.querySelectorAll('#discussion details');

const inputCheckBoxHandler = () => {
  console.log('running');
  // Change toggle button and collapse all Details elements
  if (eleInputCkbx.checked === true) {
    eleLabelIcon.classList.remove('bi-arrows-collapse');
    eleLabelIcon.classList.add('bi-arrows-expand');
    eleLabelText.textContent = ' Expand All';
    eleDetailsNL.forEach((item) => {
      if (item.open === true) {
        item.open = false;
      }
    });

    // Change toggle button and expand all Details elements
  } else if (eleInputCkbx.checked === false) {
    eleLabelIcon.classList.remove('bi-arrows-expand');
    eleLabelIcon.classList.add('bi-arrows-collapse');
    eleLabelText.textContent = ' Collapse All';
    eleDetailsNL.forEach((item) => {
      if (item.open === false) {
        item.open = true;
      }
    });
  }
};

const detailEventHandler = () => {
  // Append each Details.open boolean value to array
  const arrDetailsStat = [];
  eleDetailsNL.forEach((item) => {
    arrDetailsStat.push(item.open);
  });

  // If all Details are open then check checkbox
  if (arrDetailsStat.every((item) => item === true)) {
    eleInputCkbx.checked = false;

    // If all Details are closed then uncheck checkbox
  } else if (arrDetailsStat.every((item) => item === false)) {
    eleInputCkbx.checked = true;
    inputCheckBoxHandler();
  }

  
};

eleInputCkbx.addEventListener('input', inputCheckBoxHandler);

eleDetailsNL.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener('toggle', detailEventHandler);
});
```

```html
<div id="discussion">
    <input type="checkbox" id="expand-collapse-toggle-ckbx" class="btn-check" autocomplete="off">
    <label id="expand-collapse-toggle-btn" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-3d mb-3" for="expand-collapse-toggle-ckbx"><i class="bi bi-arrows-collapse"></i><span> Collapse All</span></label>
    <details open>
        <summary>A</summary>
        This is the first detail summary
    </details>
    <details open>
        <summary>B</summary>
        This is the second detail summary
    </details>
    <details open>
        <summary>C</summary>
        This is the third detail summary
    </details>
</div>
```